# ios facebook api not fire fbLogin

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, delegates

i need to use the facebook api:
in the appdelegate.m I have this code:

```
// Initialize Facebook
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"MY_TOKEN" andDelegate:self];

// Check and retrieve authorization information
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}
```

after, in another view I have this:

```
AppDelegate* dlg = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"offline_access", nil];

if (![[dlg facebook] isSessionValid]) {
    [[dlg facebook] authorize:permissions];
}
```

and works fine: call safari with the authorization to use my app, I click Ok to authorize and my app is called again... my app visualize the last view before the authorize, but the event

```
- (void)fbDidLogin
{
    NSLog(@"fbDidLogin");
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

in AppDelegate.m (my appdelegate have **FBSessionDelegate**) is not fired (also the other events of **FBSessionDelegate** like **fbDidNotLogin** are not fired...

where is my error?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot about this two methods and perhaps forgot to add your Facebook app id to URL types in info file. [for more detail](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/)
 
// Pre 4.2 support

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
```

// For 4.2+ support

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
    sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
```